# Invalid ModelSate because of dropdownlist with concatenated information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I had a program working perfectly. But the dropdownlist of this page had just one information of one column, so I had to add another columns to this dropdownlist, because of the users ask. When I did it, my ModelState started to be Invalid.

ERROR MESSAGE:

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'SINCO_MVC.Models.SINCO_CONCESSAO'' failed because no type converter can convert between these types

Im not seeing the reason of this error.

View:

```
   <div class="editor-field" id="IDCONCESSAO">
      <%:   Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SINCO_CONCESSAO, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.IDCONCESSAO, "Id", "Nome"), string.Empty,        
    new {  @class = "select", style = "width: 250px;" }) %>
    </div>
```

Controller (where I catch the information of the dropdownlist):

```
    // GET: /Concessao/Create
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADMINISTRADOR")]
    public ActionResult Create(SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO model)
    {

        ViewBag.IDCONCESSAO = from p in db.SINCO_CONCESSAO.ToList()
                              join c in db.MUNICIPIOS_VIEW.ToList() on p.IDMUNICIPIO equals c.ID_MUNICIPIO
                              join d in db.SINCO_TIPO_CONCESSAO.ToList() on p.IDTIPOCONCESSAO equals d.IDTIPOCONCESSAO
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = p.IDCONCESSAO,
                                  Nome = p.IDCONCESSAO + " - " + c.NOME_MUNICIPIO + " - " + d.DSTIPOCONCESSAO
                              };


        PopulateItemChoices(model);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Controller (post method):

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADMINISTRADOR")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO sinco_localidade_concessao, SINCO_CONCESSAO sinco_concessao)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO.Add(sinco_localidade_concessao);
            db.SaveChanges();

                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.IDCONCESSAO = from p in db.SINCO_CONCESSAO.ToList()
                              join c in db.MUNICIPIOS_VIEW.ToList() on p.IDMUNICIPIO equals c.ID_MUNICIPIO
                              join d in db.SINCO_TIPO_CONCESSAO.ToList() on p.IDTIPOCONCESSAO equals d.IDTIPOCONCESSAO
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = p.IDCONCESSAO,
                                  Nome = p.IDCONCESSAO + " - " + c.NOME_MUNICIPIO + " - " + d.DSTIPOCONCESSAO
                              };

       PopulateItemChoices(sinco_localidade_concessao);

       return View(sinco_localidade_concessao);
   }
```

Model:

```
namespace SINCO_MVC.Models
  {
     [MetadataType(typeof(SincoLocalidadeConcessaoMetaData))]
     public partial class SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO
            {
          public List<int> SelectedItemIds { get; set; }

          public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemChoices { get; set; }
      }

    public class SincoLocalidadeConcessaoMetaData
    {

        [Display(Name = "ID LOCALIDADE:")]
        public int[] IDLOCALIDADE { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ID:")]
        public int IDCONCESSAO { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Localidade:")]
        public virtual LOCALIDADES_VIEW LOCALIDADES_VIEW { get; set; }

        public virtual MUNICIPIOS_VIEW MUNICIPIOS_VIEW { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't guess what might be invalid about the modelstate. What does the vaidation error say about it?

Comment: You have not posted the relevant code, but a dropdownlist binds to a value type (e.g. `int`, `string`) but you appear to be trying to bind to a complex type. It would need to be something like `Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SINCO_CONCESSAO.ID, ....)` assuming your `SINCO_CONCESSAO` has a property named `ID`

Comment: And why are you trying to pass a complex object in your GET method? It wont bind! And why do you have 2 parameters in the POST method (not much of this code makes sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your answer, it was it! You can post like the answer if you want. I did a lot of changes I'm my code for tests that I did before, and I will have to adjust everything now, so that's why is confusing. But thanks again!

Comment: @Jessica, Answer added, but I suggest you consider following standard naming conventions e.g `SincoLocalidadeConcessao`, not `SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO` for class names. [Refer guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get that error message is because a dropdown list returns a value type and your trying to bind to a complex object. Your posting back the selected value of `IDCONCESSAO` (an `int` I assume) and trying to bind that to `SINCO_CONCESSAO`. You need to bind the dropdown to a property of `SINCO_CONCESSAO`, for example

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SINCO_CONCESSAO.ID, ....)
```